# if statement with dates in R

Tags: r

I have a date formatted data frame(df). A sample of it is like:

```
df<- as.data.frame(as.factor(c("16.04.2015", "04.08.2014", "11.09.2013",  "20.11.2015", "04.04.2014")))
colnames(df)<-"date"
```

Namely;

```
date
16.04.2015
04.08.2014
11.09.2013
20.11.2015
04.04.2014
```

I want to assign "1" between two specific dates. Let say I want to assign "1" dates for between 10.02.2014 and 15.08.2014.Let "value" column be defined as the assign values. So the desired output is:

```
date        value
16.04.2015  0
04.08.2014  1
11.09.2013  0
20.11.2015  0
04.04.2014  1
```

How can I do that with if statements in R? Or is there any other way? I will be very glad for any help. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `between` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, value:=(as.Date(date, '%d.%m.%Y') %between% 
                       c('2014-02-10', '2014-08-15'))+0L][]
#         date value
#1: 16.04.2015     0
#2: 04.08.2014     1
#3: 11.09.2013     0
#4: 20.11.2015     0
#5: 04.04.2014     1
```

Answer (score 4):

contrary to popular belief, it is definitely not necessary to use data table

```
df <- data.frame(date = as.Date(c("16.04.2015", "04.08.2014", "11.09.2013",
                                  "20.11.2015", "04.04.2014"), '%d.%m.%Y'))



`%between%` <- function(x, interval) x >= interval[1] & x <= interval[2]

df <- within(df, value <- 1 * (date %between% as.Date(c('2014-02-10', '2014-08-15'))))

#         date value
# 1 2015-04-16     0
# 2 2014-08-04     1
# 3 2013-09-11     0
# 4 2015-11-20     0
# 5 2014-04-04     1
```

Comment: How can I generalize the date? e.g.  c('%Y-02-10', '%Y-08-15')

Comment: @havefun do you mean something like `sprintf(c('%s-02-10', '%s-08-15'), 2018:2019)` or `sprintf(c('%s-02-10', '%s-08-15'), 2018)`?

Comment: I would like to identify the date interval for multiple years (e.g. 2011-02-10 and 2012-02-10 should return the same value). I tried the suggested code but it keeps working for only one single year no matter the interval set.

Comment: The problem is that the function `'between'` takes always the first and second dates of the interval. `x >= interval[1] & x <= interval[2]`

Comment: @havefun so you are looking for something like `x >= interval[1] & x <= tail(interval, 1)`? or `x >= interval[1] & x <= interval[length(interval)]`?

Comment: Neither. I am looking to select the same interval every year.

Comment: @havefun well it was just an example, the function need not use the first and second or first/last date in `interval`; or you could fix `interval` to be the same every time. I'm not sure how you are using the function of your particular example, could you make a new question and add your example/code there?

Comment: good idea, I posted a reproducible example here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52745151/if-statement-with-dates-in-r-generalizing-per-year