# if statement with dates in R - generalizing per year

Tags: r, date, if-statement

I start from the following question to seek generalization properties: [if statement with dates in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28383595/if-statement-with-dates-in-r)

```
df <- data.frame(date = as.Date(c("16.04.2015", "04.08.2014", "11.09.2013",
                                  "20.11.2015", "04.04.2014"), '%d.%m.%Y'))
```

I want to identify all the dates between 07-15 (%m-%d) and 12-31, e.g.

```
> date        value
> 16.04.2015  0
> 04.08.2014  1
> 11.09.2013  1
> 20.11.2015  1
> 04.04.2014  0
```

My solution is based on a solution by @rawr posted in the above question:

Function for the interval:

```
`%between%` <- function(x, interval) x >= interval[1] & x <= interval[2]
```

vector with all the possible beginning:

```
begi <- as.Date(sprintf('%s-07-15',1993:2018))

# Vector with all the possible intervals
dates <- as.Date(c(sprintf('%s-07-15',1993:2018), sprintf('%s-12-31',1993:2018)))
```

Loop using the function

```
df$value <- NA

for (i in length(begi)) {
  ind<-which(format(df$date,"%Y") == format(begi[i], "%Y"))
  df$value[ind] <- 1*(df$date[ind] %between% as.Date(c(begi[i], 
                dates[i+length(begi)])))
}
```

If I ran the `i` one by one I obtain the wanted result. However, if I ran the loop the last `i`, it overwrites the entire column instead of using only the position indicated by `ind`. Why?

Comment: Your for loop is only running 1 time.  The correct statement should be:`for(i in 1:length(begi) )`.  See the answers below for a better method for solving this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can format your dates as `%m-%d` and use string comparison

```
df$value <- as.numeric(format(df$date, '%m-%d') %between% c('07-15', '12-31'))
df
#         date value
# 1 2015-04-16     0
# 2 2014-08-04     1
# 3 2013-09-11     1
# 4 2015-11-20     1
# 5 2014-04-04     0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df$leapyear <- ifelse(as.integer(format(df$date, "%Y")) %% 4 == 0, 1, 0)
df$leapyear <- ifelse(as.integer(format(df$date, "%Y")) %% 100 == 0, 0, 1)
df$leapyear <- ifelse(as.integer(format(df$date, "%Y")) %% 400 == 0, 1, 0)

df[format(df$date, "%j") > ifelse(df$leapyear == 0, 197, 196), ]
```

thanks to [@RyanD](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6762755/ryand) for pointing out that subsetting based on day of year fails to take leap years into account

Comment: `format(as.Date('2018-07-15'), "%j") > 196` returns `FALSE`. If you change it to `>=` it returns `TRUE`, but then `format(as.Date('2016-07-14'), "%j") >= 196` returns `TRUE`. So this method doesn't work for leap years.

Comment: Didn't even think about leap years. Interesting point @RyanD.

Comment: It should return a vector of TRUE/FALSE statements indicating rows where this condition is met. `>` works on the provided data set, but obviously any operand can be used, I do not believe it is the main point.

Comment: Actually you're totally right! I completely overlooked leap years.

Comment: This should work:

`df[format(df$date, "%j") > ifelse(as.integer(format(df$date, "%Y")) %% 4 == 0, 197, 196), ]`

Comment: The logic for leap years is actually a little more complex than that. "Every year that is exactly divisible by four is a leap year, except for years that are exactly divisible by 100, but these centurial years are leap years if they are exactly divisible by 400"